# How To use PHP variable in jQuery (in Wordpress plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables

This is wordpress plugin code The following code works, but no text comes into the modal window. Error is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIoyu.png)

```php
     <?php
            $phpvariabletext =  get_post_meta( $post_id, '_billing_satis_sozlesme', true );
            // $phpvariabletext large text along with html codes

            ?>
            <a class="classa" id="view" onclick="openmodal()"> Show Contract </a>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var content = '<?php echo $phpvariabletext; ?>';
            var newmodal = new tingle.modal();
             function openmodal() {
                newmodal.open();
                newmodal.setContent(content);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I would highly advise doing something like this. Why not use [ajax](https://www.keycdn.com/support/ajax-programming) ?

Comment: May I recommend that you use `json_encode()` and NOT quote-wrap your php variable? I can't yet tell if this is a solution for your error, but it is good stabilizing practice. Also, screen shots of text = bad on Stackoverflow

Comment: **never** ever mix php and js - they're executed differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP variable in JQuery/Javascript easily check below steps

1) Stored PHP variable value in HTML input tag as type hidden

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $phpvariabletext;?>" id="phpvariable">
```

2) After assign variable value in HTML input tag. You can get value in JQuery/Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var content = $('#phpvariable').val();
        var newmodal = new tingle.modal();
         function openmodal() {
            newmodal.open();
            newmodal.setContent(content);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating extra DOM elements solely to transport a value is needless extra markup.

I always pass php data to javascript as `json_encode()` output (without manually quoting) because it will automatically double-quote your string and escape any of the double-quotes in the actual data.

```
<a class="classa" id="view" onclick="openmodal()"> Show Contract </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let newmodal = new tingle.modal();
    function openmodal() {
        newmodal.open();
        newmodal.setContent(<?= json_encode(get_post_meta($post_id, '_billing_satis_sozlesme', true)); ?>);
    }
</script>
```

The above technique outputs the php value using php "short tags".

P.s. you could also consider removing the inline js function call and use an event listener in your js to keep all of the behaviors/events in one place.